# unable to hide kendo dropdownlist from form

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have many kendo dropdownlist in a form but I just want to hide only kendodropdownlist.
Here is my code to hide:

```
$("#minpass").css("display", "none");
$("#minpass").hide();
```

I search in the internet and I found this solution , it can hide but all dropdownlist in a form disappear. this is code:

```
var minpassdropdownlist = $("#minpass").data("kendoDropDownList");
minpassdropdownlist.closest(".k-widget").hide();
```

Here is my kendodropdownlist:

```
$("#minpass").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value"
});
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this I think this will work

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.wrapper.hide(); // call for hide kendo dropdown call
 dropdownlist.wrapper.show();// to make it visible again
```

Comment: Its helpful for me!

Comment: how to do the same for kendo multi select dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any method of the kendo UI dropdownlist that can hide it. I found [destroy](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-destroy) which may be able to remove any changes done around the original select element and then you can hide it, having to redo the Kendo dropdownlist when you show it again.

The `.closest` solution should work, judging by the [control's demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index). The original input element is hidden inside a series of spans, the top one having the class `k-widget k-dropdown k-header`.